# Run a shell script using kubectl exec - OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:346

Tags: shell, kubernetes, hyperledger

I am trying a run a shell script via kubectl exec.

Eg-  kubectl exec -n abc podxyz -- /root/test/./generate.sh

The script runs in the podxyz container but returns the below error, breaking the rest of the flow.

`"command terminated with exit code 126"]`

`"OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused \"no such file or directory\": unknown"]}`

I have tried to use -- /bin/sh and bash after the -- , but that did not help.
Note - the above command is executed as part of another script.

Comment: Are you certain that `/root/test/./generate.sh` exists? What does `kubectl -n abc exec podxyz -- ls /root/test` show?

Comment: Yes, the file does exist, i have verified this, I got into the container and can see the file there

Comment: According to the bash man page, "If a command is found but is not executable, the return status is 126.". What are the permissions on the file? Can you show us the command line you used when you tried to explicitly use `/bin/bash` or `/bin/sh`?